# How Do I Horizontally Center An Operator Relative To Aligned Equations Above and Below

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, horizontal-alignment

I want to achieve the following effect in a new enviornment I'm defining where the stuff inside what's supposed to be delimeters is a \begin{aligned} \end{aligned} block.

```
\begin{equation}

                  /    math math math math math     (outside aligned)|               \lor            |
                 \     math math                 /
\end{equation}
```

This is all straightforward except I want to center the \lor inside the aligned equations, i.e., center it between the two delimiters.  How do I do this in a macro (no hand setting alignment characters)?

Do I need to make the \lor a middle delimiter or something?  Note sometimes the outside delimiters may need to be invisible if not absent entirely but \lor should still be centered inside the aligned environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally positive, but are you looking for something like this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\addlor[2][]{%
        \begingroup
        \ifx\relax#1\relax
                \mathpalette\addlor@aux{#2}%
        \else
                \addlor@aux#1{#2}%
        \fi
        \endgroup
}
\def\addlor@aux#1#2{
        \setbox0\hbox{$\m@th#1#2$}%
        \rlap{\hbox to\wd0{\hfill$\m@th#1\lor$\hfill}}%
        \box0
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\text{(outside aligned)}
\left<
\addlor{
        \begin{aligned}
        f(x)&=g(x)+h(x)\\
        &\\
        f(x)&=x
        \end{aligned}
}
\right>
\end{equation}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The `\addlor` macro takes an optional first argument that can be one of `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, or `\scriptscriptstyle`. Without the optional argument, it just uses the surrounding style.

Comment: That's great but could you explain a bit what is going on with the \setbox0 and \wd0 stuff since I kinda need to know what is going on so I can take it apart and modify stuff for my own macros.

Comment: @Peter: Sure. `\setbox0` is putting the following box (which I construct with `\hbox`) into box register 0. The `\hbox to\wd0` is constructing an `\hbox` that has the same width as box 0 (that's what `\wd0` means). So what's going on is the `\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}` is going into box 0, then I measure the width, create a new box of that width, center `\lor` in it, and then overlap that with `\box0`.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand what exactly should be in the new environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{(outside aligned)}
\left(\arraycolsep=1.35pt
        \begin{array}{@{}rl@{}}
        f(x) &= g(x)+h(x)\\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\lor}\\
        f(x) &= x
        \end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the text "outside aligned" is supposed to be, well, outside the `align` environment.